# Swiftui and firebase emulators not working on physical device / simulator

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, ios-simulator, emulation

I am working on a swiftui app and just started using the Emulator suite of firebase.
Everything is fine when i preview the app and write to a firestore collection or authenticate a user. The problem is that whenever i want to test it on a simulator or a actual physical device it does nothing. And i cannot find anything online regarding using emulator with a physical device in your local lan.

What could be stopping my physical device to make a connection with my Macbook where the emulators are running?

See my firebase.json config below:

***NOTE: i have tryed to put "host": "192.168.x.x" or "0.0.0.0" <- my macbook ip adres
But with no result.***

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ]
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  },
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099
    },
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080
    },
    "storage": {
      "port": 9199
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

**code below FirebaseApp.configure()
Where Localhost is "192.168.x.x" my macbook IP**

```
let settings = Firestore.firestore().settings
settings.host = "localhost:8080"
settings.isPersistenceEnabled = false
settings.isSSLEnabled = false
Firestore.firestore().settings = settings
```

**In the info.plist i added App transport Security Settings:
Allows local networking = YES**

What i see in debug.log (This might be unrelated)
Jul 04, 2021 10:20:53 AM io.gapi.emulators.netty.HttpVersionRoutingHandler channelRead
INFO: Detected non-HTTP/2 connection.

What could be a problem to stop my phone from connecting to my firebase emulators hosted on my macbook which is in the same local network as my phone.
When i use firebase cloud version everything works fine.
Could it be something in my firewall or on the macbook itself?
Which would explain that both physical and a simulator cannot write /read to firestore.

Hope some one can help me!
Would love to test functions and everything else locally first.

Greetings,

Dylan

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: @bze12 nope i did not. was hoping new versions of firebase would fix this.